# rmi registery problems

Tags: java, classloader, rmi, rmiregistry

Dear stack overflow users.

I've read a lot of RMI registry problems and tried them to my problem but to no success. So here is my case and I hope someone can at least help me along a bit.

I am building a multi player pacman for a school project. It is required to use the java RMI so I created 3 nice jar files. The server containing (only) a main class that publishes the thing to a remote server and loads some stuff like a map etc. The client containing some swing junk that displays some nice forms. And third a library that contains all pacman code.

Now when I start the server locally it starts a rmiregistry and binds the game to it (after setup of course). Then I connect my client to it and can play nicely. All works and I can start a view client all connecting to my local rmiregistery and get the game object nicely. 
after that I booted up the registry independent of the server and ran the program success full again. Even through the IP of my laptop (not 127.0.0.1) it worked fine. Note that I didn't set the classpath of the registry.

So after that I moved the stuff to the server(2008). I started the rmiregistry there, without a classpath and tryed to connect my server.jar to it, and failed. (could not find ..spel class exeption) so I fixed the classpath.... to no effect.... so I opened a new console started a new registry, copied the pacman.jar to c:\ and ran the server.jar with the -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=c:\ paramether.... to no effect... then I set a security manager... (`System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());`)  and made a policy containing: `grant {permission java.security.AllPermission;};` and executed the server using
server.jar -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=c:-Djava.security.policy=server.policy... with again no effect.

I keep getting the same exception:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Tervoort.Bram.Packman.Spel
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Does any one has any clue to what the problem is? and how to fix it?

Comment: o yes i tryed the -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/c:/packman.jar to.. to the same resulting error.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/faq.html) may also help.  Take a look at A.2. It seems that for what ever reason.  A class/classes can not be found at the url provided.  Make sure that the url is formed correctly and all needed classes are on the classpath.

"When a remote object is marshalled by RMI (whether as an argument to a remote call or as a return value), the codebase for the stub class is retrieved by RMI and used to annotate the serialized stub. When the stub is unmarshalled, the codebase is used to load the stub classfile using the RMIClassLoader, unless the class can already be found in the CLASSPATH or by the context classloader for the receiving object, such as an applet codebase.

If the _Stub class was loaded by an RMIClassLoader, then RMI already knows which codebase to use for its annotation. If the _Stub class was loaded from the CLASSPATH, then there is no obvious codebase, and RMI consults the java.rmi.server.codebase system property to find the codebase. If the system property is not set, then the stub is marshalled with a null codebase, which means that it cannot be used unless the client has a matching copy of the _Stub classfile in the client's CLASSPATH."

Comment: The problem is that spel in this case is the interface to the remote object and its in the paths of both the server as the client present so there should be no loading from the rmiclassloader. Except for maybe the registery